# A word for "taking something/someone serious"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

So when you `appreciate` something/someone you call this `appreciation`.

So what you call `taking something/someone serious`? and what is this characteristic called?

Comment: you mean "seriously".  one word for this is "appreciation".  but in general there is no nominalization for "taking someone seriously" that i can think of.

Comment: I would call it *seriousness*.

Answer (score 3):

**Validation** or **validating** is used symbolically to honor or offer acceptance of someone's experience.

> [To establish the soundness, accuracy, or legitimacy of: *validate a concern* - American Heritage® Dictionary, 5th Ed.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/validation)

Used symbolically thus: "Without agreeing that the setting made me nervous, too, I validated her discomfort with the situation."

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be ***respect*** as in showing respect for their ideas, etc.

> ***[Respect](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/respect)***
>
> NOUN
>
> 2. Due regard for the feelings, wishes, rights, or traditions of others.
>      *‘young people's lack of respect for their parents’*

In your case, you might say something like *I respect your concerns and will follow up with those responsible.*

Answer (score 1):

Not joking around can be considered as being [solemn](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/solemn) and the characteristic is called [solemnness](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/solemnness).

> Not cheerful or smiling; serious.
>
> *Tim looked very solemn.*